# Javascript forEach is not working for json

Tags: javascript, json, foreach

I have a ajax returning data some times like

```
{
    "results": [{
        "symbol": "AppConomy",
        "Name": null,
        "PriceSales": null
    }]
}
```

for above my forEach function is working fine but when same data is returning

```
 {
     "results": {
         "symbol": "AppConomy",
        "Name": null,
        "PriceSales": null
    } 
}
```

my forEach function not working

```
 $.get(url, function(data){
        var x =data['results'];
        x.forEach(function logArrayElements(element, index, array) {
           $(self).append('<button class="tag-format" title="'+array[index].Name+'"  style="color:#fff;background-color:rgb(0,151,216);border:1px solid;border-radius:10px;">&nbsp;'+ array[index].symbol +" - "+ array[index].PriceSales +'&nbsp;</button>');
        });
     });
```

Comment: You should use the `dot notation` : `data.results` instead of `data['results']`

Comment: [JSON is text.](http://www.json.org/) - forEach does not work on strings.

Comment: how will i know when to use dot notation when to use data['results]

Comment: $(self) is a store for "this" at beginning of script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because your JSON isn't an array. You can easily check beforehand using [Array.isArray()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray). You should also be using `getJSON` if the data you are retrieving is in fact JSON.

```
$.getJSON(url, function(data) {
    var x = data.results;
    if(Array.isArray(x)) {
        x.forEach(function logArrayElements(element, index, array) {
            $(self).append('<button class="tag-format" title="' + array[index].Name + '"  style="color:#fff;background-color:rgb(0,151,216);border:1px solid;border-radius:10px;">&nbsp;' + array[index].symbol + " - " + array[index].PriceSales + '&nbsp;</button>');
        });
    } else {
        $(self).append('<button class="tag-format" title="' + x.Name + '"  style="color:#fff;background-color:rgb(0,151,216);border:1px solid;border-radius:10px;">&nbsp;' + x.symbol + " - " + x.PriceSales + '&nbsp;</button>');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `forEach` is for iterating over an array.  In your second JSON, there is no array to iterate over, so you need to call the function directly on `data['results']`:

```
$.get(url, function(data){
  var x = data['results'],
      addButton = function(item) {
        $(self).append('<button class="tag-format" title="'+array[index].Name+'"  style="color:#fff;background-color:rgb(0,151,216);border:1px solid;border-radius:10px;">&nbsp;'+ array[index].symbol +" - "+ array[index].PriceSales +'&nbsp;</button>');
      };
  if(Array.isArray(x)) {
    x.forEach(function logArrayElements(element, index, array) {
      addButton(array[index]);
    });
  } else {
    addButton(x);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript object is not an Array.

Html

```
<div id="results"></div>
```

Javascript

```
var firstArray = {
"results": [{
    "symbol": "AppConomy",
    "Name": null,
    "PriceSales": null
}]};

var secondArray =  {
 "results": {
     "symbol": "AppConomy",
    "Name": null,
    "PriceSales": null
}};

//Result: 1
$("#results").append("<span>FirstArray result: " + firstArray['results'].length + "</span><br/>");

//Result: undefined
$("#results").append("<span>FirstArray result: " + secondArray['results'].length + "</span><br/>");
```